Resizing Cesium Viewer inside Bootstrap Accordian
I am trying to put a Cesium viewer inside a bootstrap accordion. The issue I am having is when I collapse and expand the accordion the viewer doesn't resize, even when I try to call resize or forceResize when the accordion expands.
JS code is below.
let accordian = document.getElementById("panelsStayOpen-collapse_3");
let cesiumViewerContainer = document.getElementById("cesiumContainer");
let viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {shouldAnimate: true,});
accordian.addEventListener('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log("accordian hidden")
  });
accordian.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log("accordian shown")    
        
    viewer.resize();
    viewer.forceResize();
   
  });

The viewer renders correctly on start, but once the accordion is closed and reopened the viewer is smashed into a very short line.
